# Single word to express "over-eagerness" in a negative sense

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to use the sentence

> He was 'over-eager' to implement his plan, leading to failure.

I am looking for a single word which expresses over-eagerness in a negative sense.

TIA

Comment: You need to explain what's wrong with *overeager* itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Impetuous** has a similar negative connotation. [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/impetuous):

> Acting or done quickly and without thought or care.

An *impetuous* person acts impulsively and does not think through their actions. Impetuousness would explain failure. Hence one could say the following:

> He was too impetuous in implementing his plan, which led to its failure.

Answer (score 2):

The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/134519?redirectedFrom=overeager#eid) (login required) defines 'Overeager' as an adjective meaning

> Too eager, excessively eager or keen.

The negative aspect it already encapsulated in the word and no substitution is required.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an exact fit, but the word most frequently used in that context, I would suggest, is ***impatient***.